# Lazy loading Azure Data Explorer data into a Databricks workspace

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-explorer, kql

My company is implementing Azure Data Explorer (ADX) as a backend. They also want to use Databricks for Data Science projects including data exploration. I'm in charge of connecting Databricks to ADX.

I first tried Azure Kusto package.

```
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder
from azure.kusto.data.exceptions import KustoServiceError
from azure.kusto.data.helpers import dataframe_from_result_table
import pandas as pd
...
df = dataframe_from_result_table(RESPONSE.primary_results[0])
```

Full steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/python-query-data)

Functionlly this works well.
But it loses completely the lazy loading feature of both ADX and Databricks-Spark.

I thought that because df is a just a Pandas dataframe, also if I try to convert this to a hive table it persists the data, which is not required, as we need fresh online data we don't want a local copy.

The next thing I've tried was to have this loaded in a spark dataframe. I've tried the following code (after installing the relevant libraries)

```
df = spark.read. \
format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource"). \
option("kustoCluster", KUSTO_URI). \
option("kustoDatabase",KUSTO_DATABASE). \
option("kustoQuery", "some_table_in_adx"). \
option("kustoAadAppId",CLIENT_ID). \
option("kustoAadAppSecret",CLIENT_SECRET). \
option("kustoAadAuthorityID", AAD_TENANT_ID).load()
```

which again loads the data into the spark dataframe without any issue.

However, performance wise it's far far away from the direct query in ADX. A count in a table of 600 thousands records is subseconds in ADX while it's more than 20 seconds in the Databricks notebook on a DS3_V2 14GB 4 cores.

Before even to consider a SaveAsTable or CreateOrReplaceTempView I wonder why I'm experiencing this performance issue. So my questions are :

- Does this connection use the lazy loading (I know doing a count is not the right way to check that)?
- If not is there any way to have lazy loading instea of loading the full table in dataframes before doing operations
- what would happen if I create a hive table from the spark dataframe, will it copy the data or still have a virtual table pointing to ADX

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **Python** part -
Pandas is not Spark dataframe therefore it's not lazy computed, to utilize these together you may use Spark parallelize.

For the **Spark ADX connector** -
This is indeed lazy loading. It is not evaluated until some evaluation method was requested - like the count.
If the count was done by Spark syntax i.e `spark.read.kusto...count()` then it would cause all the data to be first brought into spark and then operate count on it - so 20 seconds sounds legit, to compare with a query simply change the value of "kustoQuery" to "some_table_in_adx | count" which will lead to a count on the ADX side - uploading to spark just the final int result.
The connector offers simple Kusto query or distributed export command via the `readMode` option with `ForceSingleMode` to perform a simple Kusto query from driver node - as explained in the [docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark/blob/master/docs/KustoSource.md#supported-options)

As **Hive table** operated over dataframes - once you create a dataframe from Kusto read - it will also be lazy evaluated with table operations.